# C# - Different Settings.settings file for each developer

Tags: c#, .net, git, visual-studio

I have a problem syncing the Settings.settings with my team.

In this file I store the DatabaseConfiguration:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="DatabaseLayer.Properties" GeneratedClassName="Settings">
  <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="ConnectionString" Type="System.String" Scope="Application">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">mongodb://localhost</Value>
    </Setting>
    <Setting Name="DatabaseName" Type="System.String" Scope="Application">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">MyDatabaseName</Value>
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```

This file is automatically kept in sync with `App.config` file. So when I change a property on it, Visual Studio automatically updates my `App.config` file.

The problem is each developer on the team has a different database name, so now and then people commit their file and "breaks" others project.

The basic question is:
**How can each developer have its own ignored file with its own configuration?**

Things I have tried and couldn't make it work:

- Simply creating an ignored `User.settings` file and put the configuration on it. This has the problem that this file would also change the `App.config` file that is tracked.
- Using git `assume-unchanged` on these files, but this has to be done by each developer.

Thanks!

Comment: Having a standard DB name per project helps with this problem. I.e. Everyone on the team call their DBs the same names for the same projects

Comment: Thanks for the answer trailmax. Sure it does, the thing is this project works with several different databases in Mongo. Each developer tests different databases. Thats why its not possible to have everyone having the same DB name.